# How to change the recorded date of a video?

Tags: shotwell, tagging

I have 4 videos on my laptop which I took last year in April. But in Shotwell it shows me that it was taken in 23.04.1945. How to change this recorded date of the video?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- Select one or more photos and/or videos
- From the Photos menu, select adjust date/time

Note that if you have metadata writing on, Shotwell will write the change to photo file formats that it can support.  (Video files and RAW images will NOT be affected.)

Also since you didn't say which version of Shotwell you're using, I should point out that adjusting the date and time of a video was added in Shotwell 0.10.

Comment: That worked well. But now I have 2 times the wanted day in April '11. http://bit.ly/xK40ug

Comment: Shotwell doesn't re-use existing events.  I agree that this is a questionable design choice.  We have an open ticket to change this behavior: http://redmine.yorba.org/issues/3565

Comment: I should point out that you can manually merge the events if you like.  If you click on the month view you'll get icons for each event that month.  Then highlight two events you want to merge, right click and select Merge Events (or chose Merge Events from the Events menu)

Comment: Yeah, managed to. For example if you have 2x 24.April, you can go into one of them, mark all pictures and simply drag them in the other 24'st o April.